# How to change the background colour of SKScene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a class based on SKScene. As we know to change bg colour we have to use backgroundColor property with UIColor value.

Unfortunately my code
`self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 40.0, green:40.0, blue:40.0, alpha:1.0)` doesn't work, instead of expected result (dark grey colour) I get white (it looks that something went wrong and it uses the default colour)

I was trying to add
`self.view.allowTransparent = true` it haven't helped too.

Also my viewcontroller has my expected colour which was set in storyboard and `self.backgroundColor = .clear` also fill it with white.

How to change SKScene background colour for custom or for transparent colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to set color in 8 bit 255 rgb, but [UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor) accepts floating point value eg 0 ... 1.0.

Transform your values to floating point values.

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.157, green: 0.157, blue: 0.157, alpha: 1.0)
```